# Bars in Bar graph are of different size

Tags: c#, charts, bar-chart

I am drawing a bar chart and I saw some of them have different width than others.

I tried changing `PointWidth` and `PixelPointWidth` properties. But of no use. Here is the graph I got  :

[image]

The only configure I done is `barChart1.Series["DeltaE"]["PointWidth"] = (0.6).ToString();`

Comment: Which charting library are you using?

Comment: @adrianbanks `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have too many data and the chart is too small. Try delete some data or make the chart bigger.

I made an example. I created a c# project, put a chart in the form, randomly add some data and run the program.

When the chart is big enough, it looks well.

[image: bigger]

When the chart is smaller, not all the columns are the same width.

[image: smaller]

Comment: what is the relation between width of bars and data size?

Comment: @Zigma When the bars are only a few pixels width, even one pixel difference between two bars can make them seem different. If the chart is wide enough, say 1234px, each of the 100 bars has either 12px or 13px space. When the chart is small, say 120px, each bar has either 1px or 2px. 1px:2px looks more different than 12px:13px.

Comment: Ok , I need this to print in a paper :)